# Use .bashrc in a detached screen

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

So, I've got a bunch of `export ...` environment variable lines in my `.bashrc`, and I would like to call some programs (specifically Jupyter notebook) that need access from those notebooks from `screen`, and furthermore a screen that is initially detached.

I initially tried (in a script called `jupyter.sh`)

```
screen -dRR foobar jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

but since the detached screen is neither login nor interactive neither `.bash_profile` (which just sources `.bashrc`) nor `.bashrc` itself were sourced and so my notebook didn't have access to the definitions in them.

Then I tried digging into `.screenrc`, but it doesn't seem like there's an equivalent `export` command for screenrc, so I decided as a workaround to use a second bash script, `._juypter`, that just manually calls source before calling Jupyter notebook:

```
#!/bin/bash
source .bashrc
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

But *that* didn't work either, and I really don't know why. I think it's the `source` command that isn't doing what I want - if I insert `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH$` in between `source` and `juypter` I get an empty line at the top of my new screen, and if I put `echo "foobar"` into my .bashrc I don't see anything when the screen loads.

The *really* weird thing is, while making a new variable `export $FOOBAR="baz"` in my .bashrc and trying to `echo $FOOBAR` doesn't work either as expected, if I then `source .bashrc` manually before running the screen script `jupyter.sh`, then the `echo $FOOBAR` *does* work - I get a `baz` at the top of the screen! But even then, the thing I actually want, `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, doesn't. So now I'm *very* confused. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Bash syntax:

> FOOBAR="baz"

You have:

> $FOOBAR="baz"

Can you upload a snapshot of your current scripts to a hosting web service so that we can look at them?